# Summation of trigonometric functions results in error with finite precision

Tags: floating-point, precision, rootfinding, computer-arithmetic

Consider the following expression:

$$f(t) = B+\sum_{k=1}^{N} A_k\cos(\omega_kt)$$

where $A$ and $B$ are known. the frequencies are also known but are not multiples of a fundamental frequency. However, they are written this way (if there is any use in this information):

$$\omega_k = a_k\alpha+b_k$$

with $a,b \in \mathbb{Z} $ and $\alpha \in (0,1)$.

I have some problems.

1. My main goal is to find the zeros of the function, so an accurate and efficient method is required.
2. For some parameters, the function evaluation encounters errors due to finite precision.

In the following figures, the top depicts the function using double-precision and the bottom shows it using symbolic evaluation. Thus another objective is to evaluate the function using finite precision to achieve speed while maintaining accuracy.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean with "symbolic evaluation", do you have a "closed" expression for the series or do you mean that the symbolic library used some multi-precision module with automatic precision selection? Loss of relative accuracy due to catastrophic cancellation is generally a given at roots.

Comment: Many thanks Mr. Lehmann. Yes, I mean using extended precision. The latter figure has been obtained using symbolic variables in the software I use, it will automatically calculate the symbolic expression which does not have the shortcoming of double-precision.

Comment: More than anything else, the first figure seems to suffer from the fact that you sample at too few points. It looks like you are only sampling at 100 or 200 points. What happens if you increase that number?

Comment: Separately, how large is $N$?

Comment: Thank you Mr. Bangerth for your pertinent comment. the number of samples and the interval is the same for both figures. If I increase the number of samples, no success is achieved. Also $N$ is about 100 (although the problem can differ).

Comment: While it is not entirely clear from the data provided in the question, it appears the computation is summing terms close to 1 in magnitude, while reference results are on the order of magnitude 1e-30. This implies that performing this summing in IEEE-754 double precision (`DBL_EPSILON` ~=2.2e-16) leads to catastrophic cancellation, and the result is just noise. Even performing this computation in quadruple precision or with double-double arithmetic, or using a compensated dot product may be insufficient. Rearranging the order of summation might help, but without concrete data it is hard to say

Comment: @njuffa Thank you for your very informative comment. How about the roots? I assume the same problem occurs for computing the roots of polynomials that can be overcome using specific algorithms that do not really need to evaluate the polynomial.

Comment: For the polynomial roots, see the discussion around the exemplary case of the Wilkinson polynomial. If you consider that the floating point coefficients represent each a small set of real numbers, then among the polynomials with the same floating point representation you can find drastically different root sets.

Comment: @njuffa About the field study, it is in the area of (nonlinear) eigen-value problems. the trigonometric sum I quoted is the expansion of the determinant of a matrix whose elements are trigonometric functions. thereby, the root-finding problem forms for the eigenvalues. At first I thought it is a good idea if I expand the determinant but now I see.

Comment: @njuffa About the "reorganization" idea, thus far I could rewrite the expression as $\det(\bf P-I)$  where $\bf P$ is the product of a set of 2x2 matrices with trigonometric elements and $\bf I$ is the Identity matrix. This way, precision is achieved, but it is not very fast to evaluate. I haven't yet found a good reference in the literature that gives numerical solution of nonlinear eigenvalue problems with examples. Should I ask the main problem in another question?

Comment: @LutzLehmann Thank you, I read it. It is regarding ill-conditioned polynomials where the roots are sensitive to small perturbation of coefficients and the resolution is the change of basis. But my question is regarding how to efficiently calculate these roots.

Comment: To be absolutely sure of numerical roots for a polynomial of degree $n$ given with $b$ bits of precision you need a working precision of $nb$ bits. If you can be absolutely sure that any clusters of roots as seen on the Riemann sphere have a maximal size $k$, then $kb$ bits are sufficient. It is probably possible to have a greedy approach to this high precision with algorithms that explicitly or implicitly identify root clusters, and factor the polynomial accordingly, such as Schönhage's circle splitting method, where the factors should be reliably correct with a lower working precision.

Answer (score 2):

Some thoughts:

How many coefficients (N) are there?

If you are solely interested in the zeroes, you might get away with 'stretching' the functions by a constant factor in amplitude and/or a constant factor for the wavelength coefficients. You are currently undersampled in the region [-1e-16,1e-16], so if you strech your amplitudes to e.g. [-1e6,1e6], the slope of zero-passes will be adjustable and that might help you.

When you write your cosine as the power series expansion, you might be able to rearrange the two sums. Then you can only consider the expansion up to a certain order around a small interval. The idea is, that you do not need to calculate all cos() every time, but a power series will do if you want to find the zero-passes near some starting point.

Comment: Thank you for your pertinent answer. but I assume the conversion to power series will not help, since it will require a high number of terms and $\cos$ evaluation does not take drastic time compared to polynomials, unless we could agree that calculating the roots of the polynomial is more efficient than the trigonometric sum.